# @KafkaListener throwing error for missing topic even though class level profile not activated

Tags: java, spring-kafka

We have a configuration class with a profile of "foo".  It has a kafka listener as below:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("foo")
public class AListener {

     @KafkaListener(topics = "my.kafka.topic", autoStartup = "${kafka.listeners.auto.startup:true}")
public void processBatch(List<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> records) {
//do stuff
```

When the app starts up without foo profile active I see a kafka error in the logs complaining that my.kafka.topic does not exist (which is true but thats neither here nor there) which indicates that the listener container is being created regardless of profile.  Is this expected?  Is something else besides spring managing the listener?

Comment: Allow me a stupid question: what happens if you completely comment out yout whole method `processBatch`? Just to prove that it is really *this* method which activates the Kafka listener on this particular topic? (@GaryRussell: "Something else must be configuring a listener")

Answer (score 1):

Something else must be configuring a listener; this works as expected for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75550011Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75550011Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
@Profile("foo")
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so75550011", topics = "so75550011")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Initially, I thought it might be because it is in a `@Configuration` class (really meant for bean definitions) instead of `@Component`, but no, it works as expected for me.

If you can't figure it out, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior.

**EDIT**

This has one active listener and one inactive; works fine...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75550011Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75550011Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so75550011other").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(registry.getListenerContainerIds());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        };
    }

}

@Configuration
@Profile("foo")
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so75550011", topics = "so75550011")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}

@Component
class OtherListener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so75550011other", topics = "so75550011other")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

```
[so75550011other]
```

Only the other listener is registered.

Comment: We have several other listeners configured and working as expected.  Does having one active listener trigger the creation of all of them?

Comment: No; still works for me - see the edit.